# Where is my mistake in this exterior derivative of a $2$-form not being a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors, exterior-algebra, lie-derivative

Using the [invariant formula for the exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula), one gets that for a $3$-form $\omega$ its derivative is evaluated on vector fields according to

$$3 \ {\rm d} \omega (X, Y, Z) = X \ \omega (Y, Z) + Y \ \omega (Z, X) + Z \ \omega (X, Y) - \omega ( [X, Y], Z) - \omega ( [Y, Z], X) - \omega ( [Z, X], Y) .$$

This is supposed to be a tensor expression, but I'm having troubles verifying this. If I replace $X$ by $fX$, with $f$ a smooth function, instead of $f$ simply getting out and multiplying everything, I get the following terms containing derivatives of $f$: the second term produces $+Yf$, the third $+Zf$, the fourth $+Yf$ and the sixth $-Zf$.

Why don't the terms with $Yf$ cancel out like the ones with $Zf$? The same happens if I multiply $Y$ or $Z$ by $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do cancel, if you keep track of the signs correctly. For example, the second term produces $(Yf) \omega(Z,X)$, while the fourth produces $-\omega( -(Yf)X,Z) = (Yf)\omega(X,Z)$. These are negatives of each other because of the antisymmetry of $\omega$.

Comment: This proves that it's time for me to go to sleep.